# how do i store a in an array in C?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that calculates results of football matches.I'm trying to store the team ids' in an array with a length of 10 defined at the top but i keep getting getting a build error from the array. I realise the syntax might be wrong but how else can i use a variable to specify array length?
   The error message i'm getting is : expected expression before '{ ' token.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main() {
    int numberofmatches, hometeamid, awayteamid, hometeamgoals, awayteamgoals;
    int hometeamwins = 0;
    int winratio;
    int teamid[ARRAY_SIZE];
    printf("Enter number of matches played \n");
    scanf("%d", &numberofmatches);

    if (numberofmatches > 0) {

        int x = 0;
        do {

            printf("Enter match stats in order Home_team_ID,Away_Team_ID,Goals_Home,Goals_Away\n");
            scanf("%d %d %d %d", &hometeamid, &awayteamid, &hometeamgoals, &awayteamgoals);

            teamid[ARRAY_SIZE] = {hometeamid}; //Error is on this line

            if (hometeamgoals > awayteamgoals) {
                hometeamwins++;
            }
            x++;
        }
        while (x < numberofmatches);
        winratio = hometeamwins / numberofmatches;
        printf(" %d :teamidth %d :winratio", teamid[0], winratio);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error?

Comment: What does the error say? Is it the array or your while loop?

Comment: What you think `teamid[ARRAY_SIZE] = {hometeamid};`is doing in the middle of your loop?

Comment: Well, the line with the error has a very invalid syntax.

Comment: Please provide full verbatim quote of the error message, by editing it into the question. It would also be helpful to know the warning level you use, i.e. please show how you build. Something like `gcc -Wall mycode.c` ?

Comment: The error message i'm getting is : expected expression before '{ ' token. I realise the syntax might be wrong but how else can i use a variable to specify array length?

Comment: Do you consider `ARRAY_SIZE` a variable? If not, which variable in your code do you think has an influence? I mean even assuming that  `teamid[ARRAY_SIZE] = {hometeamid};` were a definition. I.e. would you like to answer my first question-comment? (It is considered relevant by two others at least....)

Answer (score 1):

This
`teamid[ARRAY_SIZE] = {hometeamid};`
is the syntax for defining an array of size `ARRAYSIZE` and initialising it incompletely.
You try it in the middle of a loop.

In case you want to write to an array member you probably want
`teamid[x] = hometeamid;`

Also, I recommend making sure that you do not write beyond teamid[9], which is the last legal member of the array, for ARRAY_SIZE == 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your defining an array of size 10, and then accessing it at index 10. Since arrays are indexed 0..n-1 you need to access index 9 to get the end of the array instead of 10.

Comment: That would not cause a build error.

Comment: That's a runtime error

Comment: Sorry didnt read that part of the question, until error message is updated that is the only error I can see.

Comment: Actually just tried on my machine, it does cause a build error "error C4789: buffer 'array_' of size 40 bytes will be overrun; 4 bytes will be written starting at offset 40". Because he is indexing with define, the compiler can tell the array will be overrun.

Comment: Fair point. Knowing applied warning level and verbatim error message OP gets would be nice...